# How can I change the rate of fire when shooting automatic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform[] firePoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody projectilePrefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private float launchForce = 700f;
    [SerializeField]
    private Animator anim;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool automaticFire = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
        {
            if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
            {
                anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                LaunchProjectile();
            }
        }

        if(automaticFire == true)
        {
            anim.Play("SHOOTING");
            LaunchProjectile();
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                projectilePrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0,0,1) * launchForce);

            projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }
}
```

If it's automatic :

```
if(automaticFire == true)
        {
            anim.Play("SHOOTING");
            LaunchProjectile();
        }
```

It's shooting nonstop but it looks like one long bullet.
If for example I want it to shoot nonstop but only one bullet each time ? Or shooting many bullets but with some space between them ?

On each bullet I'm adding this destruction script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletDestruction : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Init()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DestroyBullet());
    }

    IEnumerator DestroyBullet()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

But that's also a problem. If I'm setting the destruction delay to be 0.2 the bullets shoot distance is very short but if I will set the delay time for example to 5 the bullets will be shoot to a longer distance but then again there will be a lot of bullets at the same time.

What is the logic on the destruction and the automatic mode ? And how should I do it in the script/s ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
float attackRate = 100;
float timer = 0;

public void Update()
{
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(automaticFire && timer <=0)
    {
         Shoot();
         timer = 1/ attackRate;
    }
}
```